# SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple in ROS Cameracalibrator

Tags: camera, camera-calibration, ros

How to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/camera_calibration/cameracalibrator.py", line 252, in on_mouse

    self.c.do_calibration()

  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 1053, in do_calibration

    self.cal_fromcorners(self.good_corners)

  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 856, in cal_fromcorners

    flags = flags)

SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

```
def cal_fromcorners(self, good):
    # Perform monocular calibrations
    lcorners = [(l, b) for (l, r, b) in good]
    rcorners = [(r, b) for (l, r, b) in good]
    self.l.cal_fromcorners(lcorners)
    self.r.cal_fromcorners(rcorners)

    lipts = [ l for (l, _, _) in good ]
    ripts = [ r for (_, r, _) in good ]
    boards = [ b for (_, _, b) in good ]

    opts = self.mk_object_points(boards, True)

    flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC

    self.T = numpy.zeros((3, 1), dtype=numpy.float64)
    self.R = numpy.eye(3, dtype=numpy.float64)
    cv2.stereoCalibrate(opts, lipts, ripts, self.size,
                       self.l.intrinsics, self.l.distortion,
                       self.r.intrinsics, self.r.distortion,
                       self.R,                            # R
                       self.T,                            # T
                       criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 1, 1e-5),
                       flags = flags)

    self.set_alpha(0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error message using `cv2.calibrateCamera`. This [LINK](http://marc.info/?l=python-ldap-dev&m=97941947805340&w=2) suggests, that a list is given, where a tuple is expected. In my case the argument `imageSize` was the culprit.

Your `flags`, `criteria`, `T` and `R` look good, but please check for the other arguments, especially `self.size`.